# Chat between mobile device and Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, chat, p2p

I am trying to make chatting between an Android Device and an Android Emulator.My question is do they need to be on the same network to work?! What about if I tried between 2 real devices? How will I be able to detect the other device?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Do they need to be on the same network to work?!**

As long as they don't communicate via a server: Yes

**What about if I tried between 2 real devices?**

Should not make any difference. Just make sure they are on the same wifi network.
BTW, your PC running the Emulator will have to be connected to the same wifi/ethernet network as the physical Android device in case you use it.

**How will I be able to detect the other device?**

http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

Comment: @FD_...any ideas what libraries might be useful for that connection?!*P2P